# Unexpected Character > when appending html - regex escape necessary?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, syntax, asp-classic

I wonder if someone can help me understand. I was getting an AJAX response of HTML and adding it to the DOM with jQuery's .appendTo(), and getting the error:

"Unexpected character >".

After plenty of Googling and elimination debugging, I discovered it was a JavaScript function:

```
function htmlEscape(str) {
  return String(str)
      .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
      .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
      .replace(/'/g, '&#39;')
      .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
      .replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}
```

Note the final replace. If I escape that right chevron, I'm good. I ran my code through a syntax checker early on (http://esprima.org/demo/validate.html) and it said everything was valid. So I wonder if anyone can explain why this issue arose?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the browser is seeing `/>` as the end of an HTML tag.

Comment: was that function within your Ajax response?  or just on your page?

Comment: The function is within an Ajax response, which is then added to the DOM.